# How can I capture a commandline/linux command in my rails app and store the output in a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails code, I have the following code that needs to be executed within the rails application. Normally, you would run this on the command line. Her is the code defined:

```
COMMAND=->(url, port){%x"echo QUIT | openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -quiet -no_ign_eof -servername #{url} -verify_hostname #{url} -connect #{url}:#{port}"}
```

In the application, I need to execute this:

```
Model::COMMAND.call('website.com',443)
```

The "official" output of the command is an empty string. However, I see the following:

```
[53] pry(main)> SiteCheck::COMMAND.call('website.com',443)
depth=0 C = US, ST = States, L = Somewhere, O =Corp, serialNumber = 123456789, CN = www.website.com, postalCode = 12345, businessCategory = Private Organization, street = JFK Random Street, jurisdictionST = Nevada, jurisdictionC = US
verify error:num=62:Hostname mismatch
verify return:1
depth=3 C = PL, O = Unizeto Technologies S.A., OU = Certum Certification Authority, CN = Certum Trusted Network CA
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, ST = States, L = Somewhere, O = Corporation, CN = EV Root Certification Authority RSA R2
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = States, L = Somewhere, O = Corp, CN = EV SSL Intermediate CA RSA R3
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = States, L = Somewhere, O = Corp, serialNumber = 123456789, CN = www.website.com, postalCode = 12345, businessCategory = Private Organization, street = JFK Random Street, jurisdictionST = Nevada, jurisdictionC = US

verify return:1
DONE
=> ""
```

What I paricularly need is the `verify error: num=62 Hostname mismatch` part. How can I capture this? I tried to use pop3 but my problem is that the return value is an empty string so in a way, I am getting a returned result, just not what I want. Is there a way I can capture it in ruby?

Comment: That output is going to stderr.

Comment: take a look at [`open3`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Open3.html) instead it offers access to stdin, stdout and stderr

Comment: Oh ok, maybe I didn't look hard enough into stderr and open3. Thank you guys I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

That output goes to stderr. You can use `Open3.capture3`:

```rb
require 'open3'

stdin, stderr = Open3.capture3(
  "openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -quiet -no_ign_eof -servername #{url} -verify_hostname #{url} -connect #{url}:#{port}",
  stdin_data:'QUIT'
)
```

Also instead of spawning a process - you can try initiating that connection from ruby itself:

```rb
require 'openssl'
require 'socket'

def ssl_connect_verify(host, port)
  context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
  context.ca_file = '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' # this is for mac, your path may differ
  context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

  tcp_client = TCPSocket.new host, port
  ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(tcp_client, context)
  ssl_client.hostname = host # SNI
  ssl_client.connect

  if (san_ext = ssl_client.peer_cert.extensions.select{|e| e.oid == 'subjectAltName' }.first)
    dns_names = san_ext.value.split(/,\s*/).map{|s| s.delete_prefix "DNS:"}
    unless dns_names.any?{|san| OpenSSL::SSL.verify_hostname(host, san)}
      raise "Cannot verify hostname..."
    end
  end

  ssl_client.peer_cert_chain.map{|cert|
    # cert is a OpenSSL::X509::Certificate, see documentation on its fields
    cert.subject.to_s
  }
rescue OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError => e
  # check for error message etc.
  puts "Cannot connect: #{e.to_s}"
  return []
ensure
  ssl_client.close
end


puts ssl_connect_verify('google.com', 443).join("\n")
```